# Ajax call return viewmodel but the view does not display results

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to display the returned model from a method in my partial view. The call is made with Ajax and the method returns a viewModel. The partial view is in a modal, so when the button is clicked, the call is made to the method and the partial view is displayed. In the partial view if I debug I can see that is has data in it, but when I loop through it it doesn't display the results in @item.Users.Email or any of users property.

What i'm doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
 [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult GetUsersForJob(int? id)
    {
        WhoBidForJobViewModel vm = new WhoBidForJobViewModel();
        var bids = (from j in _context.BidOfJobs where j.JobPostId == id       select j).ToList();
        List<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
        foreach (var item in bids)
        {
            var user = (from u in _context.Users where u.Id ==        item.UserWhoBidId select u).First();
            users.Add(user);
        }
        vm.Users = users;

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
```

This is the controller with the method being called from Ajax.

```
@model  FinalWorkFinder.Models.WhoBidForJobViewModel
   <ul class="interested-people">
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    <li>@Model.Users</li>
}

  </ul>
```

This is the partial view which is inside the modal.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUsersForJob", "Manage")',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "JSON",
        cache:false,
        data: { id: idd },
        success: function (users) {
            $(".modal-title").html("Interested Users");


                console.log(users);

            }


    });
```

and this is the Ajax call.

Comment: If i understand correctly you have a partial view sent out to the js Ajax call and you want to show it inside the modal as if it would be rendered on server side?

Comment: What i see in the code is that you have @Model instead of item in the loop.

Comment: @AlexCr Basically what I`m sending with Ajax, is a JobId which is int. Then,  I make a retrieve with all jobs related to that id and put it in a modelView which the partial view uses so that I can do a foreach in the view and display a list of jobs.

Comment: the (@)Model was for testing purposes, if I do a foreach and then loop through @Model.Users and I do item.Email. Although I can debug it and clearly see the Email there, it doesn't put the value in my <li>

Comment: The problem is your mixing server side rendering with client side rendering what you get with the ajax call is a HTML syntax wich you could easily overwrite with JQuery since you are using it already. Your c# code is fine.

Comment: $(".modal-title").load('@Url.Action("GetUsersForJob", "Manage",new {id =item.id})');

Comment: (Client) Ajax Call -> (Server side) Method call ->(Server side) Partial view rendering -> (Server s.) Serialize HTML to string -> (Clien side) Users.data contains HTML text-> ???? <- here is the question what u do with it

Comment: I am assuming you are getting a html in the console? - `console.log(users);`. In that case I do not see any code which sets returned html anywhere in the UI. Put the html in a container like - `$(".container").html(users);`

Comment: @MannanBahelim doesn't work

Comment: @AlexCr for some reason if I do console.log(users) now it displays HTML text and I don't know why. specifically an ul element. I want to created basically an ul and inside that ul some li with names.

Comment: @Rahatur yes, it is a html ..

Comment: Yep that´s what you see is the element that u wanted like i said you have to distinguish between server side rendering and client side rendering. In this case you have to overwrite the html in the modal with $(".#YOURMODALCONTAINER.SELECTOR#").html(users); like Rahatur wrote in the comments.

Comment: @AlexCr I understand this, but if I console log the users they don`t have any users in it...they display the div container which is empty..

Comment: but the method return modelView. Maybe I shouldn`t return the model view and I should return something else?

Comment: <div class="containerr">

</div> this is what I get with what you said.

Comment: return PartialView(vm); <- here you have to specify the element name like return PartialView("_SomePartialView", vm);

Answer (score 1):

Try This & show me your code for `idd`

```
$.ajax({
       url:'/GetUsersForJob/Manage',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "JSON",
        cache:false,
        data: { id: idd },
        success: function (users) {
            $(".modal-title").html("Interested Users");


                console.log(users);

            }


    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed it in the end.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So after a long chat and discussion the result is:

```
public PartialViewResult GetUsersForJob(int? id)
{
    WhoBidForJobViewModel vm = new WhoBidForJobViewModel();
    var bids = (from j in _context.BidOfJobs where j.JobPostId == id       select j).ToList();
    List<ApplicationUser> users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    foreach (var item in bids)
    {
        var user = (from u in _context.Users where u.Id ==        item.UserWhoBidId select u).First();
        users.Add(user);
    }
    vm.Users = users;

    return PartialView("_partialView", vm);
}


$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUsersForJob", "Manage")',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "JSON",
        cache:false,
        data: { id: idd },
        success: function (users) {
            $(".modal-title").html("Interested Users");

$("modal.selector.body").html("users");
                console.log(users);

            }


    });
```

Comment: return PartialView("GetUsersForJob",vm); this is what I`m doing and it is still empty....arghhh I have put a break point in the GetUsersForJob partial view to check that the model is actually filled with data, and it is clear that I have data there. so I do a 
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    @item.FullName 
   
}, the item.fullname has a name... and it should be presented in the text, because I return the partial view within the modal...I`m right so far?

Comment: Can you please paste in the whole partial view with the name?

Comment: What you can do is speicify in ajax call that you await an html like "dataType: "html" "